# When I build a popupWindow from a dialog in Android 9.0, whose positionX is minus, the left content of popupWindow is clipped

Tags: android, frameworks, android-popupwindow

When I build a `popupWindow` from a dialog in Android 9.0, whose `positionX` is negative, the left content of `popupWindow` is clipped. I tried this on all other systems (before 9.0), it works normal, `popupWindow` normally was shown left of the dialog.
There are two pictures below, left is 8.0, and right is 9.0. I want to know whether it is a bug of system, or new feature of 9.0, and how can I let the `popupWindow` show without clipping?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I meet this question, too.And I find it's normal with theme Material and DeviceDefault.
You can set Material or DeviceDefault theme to your app.Or setTheme(Material/DeviceDefault) when show popupwindow, And setTheme(theme before) when hide popupwindow.